# Error in inherits(x, "Date") : argument "x" is missing, with no default Rstudio

Tags: r, loops, as.date

I need to create a function where the output is a vector filled with dates. I´ve started with

```
vlf=function(x)
{
  output=c(as.Date)
  for(i in (seq(as.Date("2015/09/1"),as.Date("2018/09/1"),by=365))){
    output=c(output,
         ifelse(x>i,x+30,0))
  }
  return(output)
}
```

Where "x" is a vector of dates
The problem is that when I try to execute it, I read this error:

```
Error in inherits(x, "Date") : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Do you know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You say

```
output=c(as.Date)
```

That sets `output` to the function, not the result of calling the function.  Use

```
output <- as.Date(x)
```

There is no need for `c()`, and `<-` is better than `=` in R.